# How can I prove control of HD wallet through message signing?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, message-signing

If I sign a message with one of the address from an HD wallet, does that prove control over the rest of the addresses created and will be created inside that HD wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It proves that you control all children of that address (i.e. the ones further **down** the chain). It does not prove that you own the parents of that address (i.e. the ones further **up** the chain), since it's not possible (AFAIK) to go from a child to a parent key.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can figure out the first address in an armory hd wallet?

Comment: Double click on the wallet to open it; the addresses are listed, with a "#" column. The one with a # of 1 is the first.